# Using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management to create ALTER scripts

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm writing .Net code to alter existing SQL Server schema automatically (adding columns, altering triggers and stored procedures). Rather than do it directly, I'd like to produce a SQL script.

In an effort to avoid reinventing the wheel, I've been looking at `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management`. As far as I can tell, the scripting elements of this library are for producing scripts that export the current state of an object.

Can anyone tell me whether I'm missing something here, or is this not the tool for the job?

Comment: Why are you altering SQL schema in .NET? Altering schema shouldn't be a run of the mill thing, If you create the schema correctly in the first place then this should be a non issue.

Comment: For tasks like adding auditing to existing tables.

Comment: If it's a one time thing then do it directly in SQL.

Comment: It's for a large number of tables across a number of databases. Also will be useful for new tables in the future.

Comment: I'll be honest, I would refuse to let this be done in the way you are asking in the company I work for. It would be better to make a little script for each table and ensure that they're tested individually. You may run into some real problems, what if your generated script keeps adding columns every time? How would you know? How would you fix it?

Comment: My question is more about how than why. But having the scripts generated enforces consistency, and allows them to be unit tested.